# So is that possible to using iterator access all element in 2 dimensional vector just like pointer?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, 2d

Look at following code (I know it's not right):

```
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> ivec(2, std::vector<int>(9));
    for (auto it = ivec.begin(); it != ivec.end(); it++)
    {
        for (auto itr = it.begin(); itr != it.end(); itr++)
        {
            std::cout << *itr << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

I've set up a 2 dimensional vector **ivec**. Now I want to access the each element using iterator instead subscripts. I know pointer is a special iterator. So is that possible to using iterator access all element in 2 dimensional vector just like pointer?

Comment: A vector of vectors isn't laid out in memory the same way a 2-dimension array is. Each vector allocates its own chunk of memory which might be anywhere. So you could probably write an iterator that handles it but it's not just as simple as incrementing a pointer.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I do not know how a vector of vectors lay out in memory, now. But you offer me some useful information, too. Also thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked:

> So is that possible to using iterator access all element in 2 dimensional vector just like pointer?

Yes, it is.

The idea is sound. You have syntax errors in your posted code though.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> ivec(2, std::vector<int>(9));
for (auto it = ivec.begin(); it != ivec.end(); it++)
{
    // for (auto itr = it.begin(); itr != it.end(); itr++)
    for (auto itr = it->begin(); itr != it->end(); itr++)
    {
        std::cout << *itr << std::endl;
    }
}
```

You can simplify that further using range-`for` loops.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> ivec(2, std::vector<int>(9));
for (auto& it : ivec)
{
    for (auto itr : it)
    {
        std::cout << itr << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does that answer the OP's question?

Comment: @JonathanPotter, I think I have answered the OP's question. Perhaps I am missing something that you noticed.

Comment: @RSahu I believe the question was how to iterate across both dimensions using a single iterator. Perhaps I misunderstood.

Comment: @sydridgm. Would you please respond the above comment by Jonathan? Thanks.

Comment: Both of your examples are actually C++11, due to use of `auto`.

Comment: @Peter, thanks for pointing out :) :) The mind is a mystery some times.